# Assumptions of Naive Bayes and Logistic Regression

Tags: machine-learning, classification, naivebayes

Am trying to understand the difference in assumptions required for Naive Bayes and Logistic Regression.

As per my knowledge both Naive Bayes and Logistic Regression should have features independent to each other ie predictors should not have any multi co-linearity.

and only in Logistic Regression should follow linearity of independent variables and log-odds.

Correct me if am wrong and is there any other assumptions/differences between Naive and logistic regression

Answer (score 0):

You are right durga. Them two have similar performances as well. 
A difference is that NB assumes normal distributions, whereas logistic regression does not. As for speed, NB is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Logistic regression, according to [this source](https://www.statisticssolutions.com/assumptions-of-logistic-regression/):

1) Requires observations to be independent of each other.  In other words, the observations should not come from repeated measurements or matched data.

2) Requires the dependent variable to be binary and ordinal logistic regression requires the dependent variable to be ordinal.

3) Requires little or no multicollinearity among the independent variables.  This means that the independent variables should not be too highly correlated with each other.

4) Assumes linearity of independent variables and log odds.

5) Typically requires a large sample size.  A general guideline is that you need at minimum of 10 cases with the least frequent outcome for each independent variable in your model.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr:**

Naive Bayes requires conditional independence of the variables. Regression family needs the feature to be not highly correlated to have a interpretable/well fit model.

Naive Bayes require the features to meet the "conditional independence" requirement which means:

[image]

This is very much different than the "regression family" requirements. What they need is that variables are not "correlated". Even if the features are correlated, the regression model might only become overfit or might become harder to interpret. So if you use a proper regularization, you would still get a good prediction.